# What is the quickest way to import a JSON object created on the client?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have an app that allows the user to select an excel file from there computer and it breaks it down into a JSON object so that it can be imported into the store. is `this.store.pushPayload('part',payload)`the quickest and most efficient way to add around 300 records to the store without hitting the server?

Running the latest beta of ember-data and ember.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`push` is the preferred method to put one normalized object in the store, `pushMany` does the same thing but with a collection of the same type:

http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_pushMany

If you need your data to be normalized by the adapter, you should call `pushPayload`.